# Nagios plugins location

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have ubuntu ec2 instance I want to monitor.I havent installed plugins on NRPE server which is using xinetd but instead I have configured and installed plugins on Nagios server.However except check_ssh nothing gets executed when I test from libexec directory from Nagios server.I have elasticsearch ,cassandra and tomcat plugins and my Boss doesnt want anything on ec2 instance except nrpe.I have already configured all these processes to accept any connections.

Comment: Do you check NRPE service status on localhost? What results of `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost` ?

Comment: NRPE is ok,just wondering can i install plugins only on nagios machine @StanislavIvanov

Comment: Plugins should be installed with same machine with NRPE agent. Agent calls plugins by NAGIOS server request and send results. At server you can install plugins only for monitoring of external available services  (ping, http, remote sql, ...)

Comment: @StanislavIvanov,To run external plugins for tomcat,elasticsearch,cassandra should I install plugins on nagios server.Currently my remote machine accepts nothing but 5666, although 7199,1099,8080 is open on that machine.Please explain as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can have two different types of host check:

1. direct check (nagios -> command `check_ping(HOSTADDRESS)` -> local plugin `check_ping(HOSTADDRESS)`);

In this case no plugins or NRPE or something else required on Second machine. Nagios calls local plugin `check_ping`, it's make a check, Nagios gets the result. You can use this type of check for PING, HTTP GET, SNMP Checks, SQL Query, etc. everything which available over the network.

2. NRPE check (nagios -> command `check_nrpe(HOSTADDRESS,COMMAND)` -> local plugin `check_nrpe(HOSTADDRESS,COMMAND)` -> (network) -> NRPE Server command `COMMAND` -> local (for NRPE) plugin `check_load` )

In this case Nagios calls local plugin `check_nrpe`, this plugin calls NRPE server, NRPE server calls its own local plugin `check_load` and return the result over the network. At Second machine should be installed NRPE and Nagios Plugins, also `nrpe.cfg` should contain necessary commands.  You can use this type for CPU Load, Memory usage and Disks space monitoring, or create custom plugins.

Configuration example:

First machine (Nagios Server):

`command` section:

```
define command{
        command_name    check_ping
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p 5
        }

define command{
        command_name    check_nrpe
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

`service` section:

```
define service{
        use                 network-service
        hostgroup_name      common-linux-servers
        service_description PING
        check_command       check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }

define service{
        use                     network-service
        hostgroup_name          common-linux-servers
        service_description     Current Load
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
        }
```

Second machine in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`:

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
```